# The Pi day and rational point on the ball

Tags: inequality, recreational-mathematics, pi

Well it's a question about the pi day :

If we have the pi day we need a place to it :

Consider the earth as ball  such that :

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=40000$$

Now can we find all the rational point on the ball  such that  $\gcd(\lfloor x \rfloor,\lfloor y \rfloor,\lfloor z \rfloor,314)=1$

To find it I have used  Bezout's theorem without reach the goal. I have tried also three square theorem due to Legendre  .

How to find it ?

Comment: I think it's a bit hard to establish what's new and what's not :(

Comment: For MSE question we can do something I think.

Comment: How is this even related to *pi day*?

Comment: Why downvotes ? $\pi$ day is coming and fun is allowed

Comment: +1 for reminding us of pi day. Happy pi day

Comment: For what it is worth, there is a similar question asked on [Math Ed SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/26210/).  This *kind* of question might be more appropriate there, but it still needs more focus and better objective criteria for what a "correct" answer should look like ("new" is hard to define, as is the condition of whether or not $\pi$ plays a "central" role).

Answer (score 1):

Without computing it, prove that, if
$$I=\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(\frac{x^{2}}{\pi^{2}}\right)^{-x}}{\left(x!\right)^{2}}dx $$
$$\frac{1}{\pi }\binom{\pi !}{\pi } < I <\sqrt{\pi } \binom{\pi !}{\log (\pi )}$$

Comment: Sorry i change the question to be reopen.